# Can typescript's type system guarantee that all possible values of a type are used?

Tags: typescript

Assume I have two types:

```
type Season = 'WINTER' | 'SUMMER';
type Activity = 'SKIING' | 'SNOWBOARDING' | 'SWIMMING' | 'SUNBATHING'
```

and also

```
seasonActivities: Record<Season, Activity []> = {
WINTER = ['SKIING', 'SNOWBOARDING'],
SUMMER = [ 'SWIMMING', 'SUNBATHING']
}
```

Is there any way of using the type system to guarantee that `seasonActivities` contains all possible values of `Activity`?

Is there any way of using the type system to guarantee that `seasonActivities` does not contain duplicate values of `Activity`?

Comment: This is really two questions, but the answer to both of these is "you can use the type system to discourage repeated/missing elements but it's not particularly pretty".  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.